# opencart : where the textbox and button function will be implemented

Tags: php, opencart

I have created 1 textbox and button in admin page. To update the mass price of product. Now I need to know where the button functions will be implemented.

I have added a button.

```
<button type="submit" form="form-product" formaction="<?php echo $sp; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_silver; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button> </div>
```

Comment: You want to update all products prices with one click?

Comment: yes. exactly...

Comment: I have added a button. <button type="submit" form="form-product" formaction="<?php echo $sp; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_silver; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
        </div>

Comment: created sp() function in controller. but its not calling the function.

Comment: Where and in which file? which version of opencart?

Comment: 2.0.1.1. i need to get the text from the textbox. I button is working well now.

Comment: Do you write any sql query?

Comment: yes. I did. query is working perfectly

Comment: when i supposed to pass the textbox value, it shows undefined variable